# How to escape HTML entities?

Tags: html, html-entities

How can I display HTML entities as their HTML representation, not as the equivalent Unicode character?

If I have `&#x0902;` and I want it to display as `&#x0902;` on my page instead of displaying as ं, how do I do that?.

Comment: `&#x0902;` is an HTML entity.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario what is the difference ?

Comment: I was just informing you about the name of the feature. Names are useful when you need to look up information or ask questions in forums :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simply encode the `&` character as `&amp;` -- so it should be printed as `&amp;#x0902`

Comment: Don't you mean: If you encode `&` as `&amp;` the encoded string will look like `"&amp;#x0902;"` and printed as `&#x0902;`?